# Is usage of 'go beyond somethings to something' correct?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, prepositional-phrases, sentence-usage

I write as follows：

> Choosing to do my master in X would be my ever best decision. Studying at the international university brings me not only its top educational quality and academic research, but also a wider horizon, making my insights **go beyond one lab or one university to the whole European and the world**.

Here I use 'go beyond one lab to the whole world' to express that before I study at X, my horizon is short and only focus on one lab. After studying at X, my horizon is wider and focus on the whole world not only the local lab. Is this usage correct?

And I also think something seems not fluent in above written paragraph, but I cannot figure it out clearly. Can you help me to correct this paragraph and make if more fluent?

Comment: As you say, it's not idiomatic. The expression **making my insights go beyond** is awkward and does not suit your purpose.  Prefer **master's degree** to **my master** (sounds like a person.)  Also, prefer **laboratory** to the informal **lab**.  **Ever best** doesn't work. Possibly **best ever**. Give it another shot.

Comment: **Best ever** and **the whole of Europe**.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, there are more than a few problems with this paragraph, but since the question asked specifically about the usage of "*go beyond*", all one can say is that it is grammatically used correctly.

In terms of the impression it makes though, rather than "*making* my insights go", it would be better to say "*allowing* my insights to go".  The first one makes it seem like you need the university to force you to do something, whereas the second one makes it seem like you want to do something that you are currently prevented from doing.

- master ⇒ master's degree
- my ever best decision ⇒ my best ever decision ⇒ the best decision I've ever made
- one lab ⇒ one laboratory
- to the whole European ⇒ to the whole of Europe